# Network Start error

Tags: networking, 14.10, network-manager

I use Ubuntu 14.10 desktop X64 and when I switch from `single usermode` to `init3`  mode  I face no network connection  so i use the command `NetworkManger`  to start it but I get this error

```
(NetworkManager:3789): GLib-WARNING **: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: Key file does not have group 'connectivity'
```

what is the meaning of this error and how to solve the man issue ?

Comment: Please upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu (15.10) and report back. Thanks.